# How to remove subtotal in SSRS Excel export

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, aggregation, ssrs-2012

I have been using SSRS to create reports recently. In one of my reports has multiple groups breakdown (From big group drilling down to intermediate group and then to individual group)

When I do a preview in Visual Studio, I get a good looking table like this:

[image]

When I export this report template into an Excel file and expand those buttons, it gives me a table like this:

[image]

As we can see there are extra rows and columns in the second picture (which are row and column subtotal). I don't really need these subtotals and for the row total it doesn't even make sense in my case (I want to compare between left and right rather than sum them up)

I have searched on a lot of website so far none of them gave me a proper answer. Some even says there is no way to hide/eliminate/disable subtotal.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no feature to automatically add a subtotal when you export. You have a row in your table with those sums. All you need to do is delete that last row in the table. If you can't see it in the design view, you probably collapsed it at some point.

Comment: Hi @StevenWhite, thanks for your response. I just checked what you said. I expand all possible rows and columns there is no subtotal. Also I tried using report wizard and manually create a matrix. They both gave me a subtotal. I also checked my report in design view and I didn't find a row with those sums

Answer (score 0):

According to Microsoft, it's a SQL Server 2008 R2 bug when you export to Excel using toggle item (it generates an automatic subtotal row out of no where), but I'm using SQL 2012 11.0.2 plus VS2010, and I too have that problem.

So far the only "fix" is to have a static row right beneath your regular data row (where the subtotal row is appearing), then manually set its visibility to false. Kinda like fooling Excel into setting it to hidden.

But this "fix" will screw up the toggle item feature.

Original Post: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f36f87b4-1d55-4db3-81e9-e8ef17b56712/getting-extra-column-while-exporting-ssrs-report-into-excel?forum=sqlreportingservices

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to show or hide report elements depending on whether it is to be rendered in Excel.

Having wrangled the excel export beast for a while, I finally decided to go this route:

1. Add an extra parameter to indicate whether the report is to be formatted for exporting ( a simple boolean or yes/no dropdown ).
2. In the report, made a copy of the tablix, and removed most groups (we use about 4 levels).
3. Using the new parameter, hide or show [tablix_original] and [tablix_simplified], and any other elements that you require.

It's a kludgy workaround, but the users love it.

Did this in [reporting-services-2016](/questions/tagged/reporting-services-2016)